# Dalvik opcodes - The application waits when calling makeDefaultPhone()

Tags: java, android, smali

I can not be used in com.android.internal.telephony in Android SDK? Okay! I decided to try to do this using smali/dalvik opcodes.

```
PhoneFactory.makeDefaultPhone(this);
```

And application waits. Why?

Comment: Smali seems like overkill.  This is simply done with Reflection/Introspection.  There are any number of reason that it might hang.  Did you read the code, here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/f39de086fddea9e9f6b8c56b04d8dd38a84237db/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/PhoneFactory.java

Comment: Yes. I have read this code. Is it possible to do using reflection? How to do it?

Comment: Roughly: Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory).getMethod("makeDefaultPhone", Context.class).invoke(ctxt);

Comment: What is `ctxt`?

Comment: i need too in method `getDefaultPhone` which call using reflection don't really

Comment: Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory).‌​getMethod("getDefau‌​ltPhone").invoke()

Comment: `NoSuchMethodException - makeDefau‌​ltPhone [class android.content.Context]`

Comment: It's impossible :(

Comment: It is quite possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143754/can-a-telephony-phone-object-be-instantiated-through-the-sdk

Comment: OMG!!  I'm add to sdk it's com.android.internal.telephony! Yeeeeesss!!!